# Is cassandra-driver-core dependency removed as part of DSE Cassandra 5.x Java driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

With DSE Cassandra 5.x, in the client code is cassandra-driver-core to be excluded from dependency due to deprecation? Is dse-java-driver-core to be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're referring, I think that the primary reason is rework of the authentication support, and other things that are specific to DSE driver. OSS driver supports only username/password authentication, while DSE driver also supports Kerberos, plus mixed internal/external authentication schemas.

But you can safely replace `cassandra-driver-core` with `dse-java-driver-core` - code is compatible, the same `Cluster`/`Session`, only if you don't need geo types, graph support, etc. Look [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/appDevGuide/aboutDrivers.html) for full list of differences.